# Mocked SignInManager not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, moq, identity, razor-pages

I am mocking a login procedure for asp.net identity and to my surprise `_mockSignInManager.Setup(
                x => x.PasswordSignInAsync(It.IsAny<IdentityUser>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<bool>())).ReturnsAsync(SignInResult.Success);`

does not return `SignInResult.Success`. In the code I will show below `var result` returns `null` and breaks the program. It is very odd to me because `CreateAsync()` with UserManager returns `Task<IdentityResult>` and this `PasswordSignInAsync()` returns `Task<SignInResult>`. Yet that other test works fine and this does not. Code below:

#### LoginModelTests

```
[TestFixture]
public class LoginModelTests
{
    private Mock<FakeSignInManager> _mockSignInManager;
    private Mock<LoginModel.InputModel> _mockInputModel;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _mockSignInManager = new Mock<FakeSignInManager>();
        _mockInputModel = new Mock<LoginModel.InputModel>();
        SetUpFakeSignInManager();
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task OnPostAsync_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior()
    {
        // Arrange
        var unitUnderTest = new LoginModel(_mockSignInManager.Object, _mockInputModel.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await unitUnderTest.OnPostAsync("/asdsad/asda");
        var okResult = result as OkObjectResult;

        // Assert
        if (okResult != null && okResult.StatusCode == 200)
            Assert.Pass();
    }

    private void SetUpFakeSignInManager()
    {
        _mockSignInManager.Setup(
            x => x.PasswordSignInAsync(It.IsAny<IdentityUser>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>(),
                It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Success));
    }
```

#### LoginModel

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, InputModel inputModel)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        Input = inputModel;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `PasswordSignInAsync` you setup for the test and the one called in the method under test have different signatures.

Comment: Yes!!! thanks @Nkosi . Can't believe I missed that, all tests pass successfully :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`PasswordSignInAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2) you setup for the test and the one called in the method under test have different signatures.

So you are setting up the wrong method.

Update the setup

```
_mockSignInManager.Setup(
    x => x.PasswordSignInAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<bool>(),
        It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Success));
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how I can go about testing a method if with many `if` statements within it? Thanks in advance

Comment: @steve that depends on how the method is defined as there are many different ways to approach it.

Comment: for example the `if(result.Suceeded)` above had two other if's which I left out for question simplicity. Say there were other conditions like `if(result.RequiresTwoFactor)` how would I account for that?

Comment: @steve By writing another test where the mock returns the required condition that would allow the code to flow/behave as expected